# Only the first item in UEFI boot order is visible in system boot menu

Tags: linux, windows, boot, multi-boot, uefi

I have an Intel NUC8i7HVK running BIOS HNKBLi70.86A, with Arch Linux and Windows 10 on different partitions of a single M.2 drive. When I open the system boot menu, only the first item in the boot order appears. I can see the other options in `efibootmgr` (in Linux) and `bcdedit` (in Windows), and changing the order switches which one the system boots from, and which single entry shows up if I restart into the boot menu.

BootNext doesn't seem to have an effect, either. If Linux is first in the boot order and I run `efibootmgr -n 2; reboot`, the system still reboots into Linux.

Here's a screenshot of the boot menu with Linux first:

[image: The BIOS boot menu only shows "arch" as an option.]

And here's the boot menu after running `sudo efibootmgr -o 2,1,0` to put Windows first:

[image: The BIOS boot menu only shows "Windows" as an option.]

I can grab the output of various `efibootmgr` and `bcdedit` command lines on request.

Any idea what might be going on here and if there's a way I can make the other options visible?